# How can i make two objects out of one object, dividing them by a value in the object with lodash

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, lodash

Consider this object, with two channels with NL language and one with EN language:

```
[
    {
        "name": "De Redactie",
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "headlines",
                "pubDate": "2017-05-15 09:15:00",
                "language": "nl",
                "items": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "headlines English",
                "pubDate": "2017-05-14 18:05:00",
                "language": "en",
                "items": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "politiek",
                "pubDate": "2017-05-14 20:11:00",
                "language": "nl",
                "items": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can i divide them so that i can get this result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "De Redactie",
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "headlines",
                "pubDate": "2017-05-15 09:15:00",
                "language": "nl",
                "items": [

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "politiek",
                "pubDate": "2017-05-14 20:11:00",
                "language": "nl",
                "items": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "name": "De Redactie",
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "headlines English",
                "pubDate": "2017-05-14 18:05:00",
                "language": "en",
                "items": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Mind you that this is dummyData. The actual data can contain x amount of one language and y amount of the second or third or fourth ...

I have tried looking in the lodash documentation for the correct combination of functions. Also tried various complex forEach structures, but could not wrap my head around it.

Preferably a solution with lodash or typescript, as i'm working in Angular 4.

Comment: The data and the result are an array with objects? If so, please update the question to include the original data structure, and the end result.

Comment: this is a simplified version of the original data. its way too big to post in the question

Comment: I know. I don't want all the data, just the structure. Do you have a single object with all the data inside, or is this object is part if a larger array? Does the end result is an array?

Comment: @Ori Drori. I see, i thought i had the correct data structure but I indeed forgot to add the array. Now it's the correct data structure, sorry about that.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen i appreciate you explanation of the downvote. But 'no attempt' is kinda harsh, i merely forgot to add the parent array, my bad. Is fixed now.

Comment: Thats a wierd assumption to make

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161191/discussion-between-martijn-van-den-bergh-and-robby-cornelissen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the array with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). For each object, extract the array of channels using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with [object rest](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/). Iterate the channels using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and group channels with the same language to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Convert back to an array by spreading the [Map's values iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values).

Create an array of objects, by mapping them and assigning the group as the `channels` prop of the object. Flatten the array by spreading into [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [{"name":"De Redactie","channels":[{"name":"headlines","pubDate":"2017-05-15 09:15:00","language":"nl","items":[]},{"name":"headlines English","pubDate":"2017-05-14 18:05:00","language":"en","items":[]},{"name":"politiek","pubDate":"2017-05-14 20:11:00","language":"nl","items":[]}]}];

const result = [].concat(...data.map(({ channels, ...rest }) => {
  const channelGroups = [...channels.reduce((m, channel) => {
    m.has(channel.language) || m.set(channel.language, []);
    m.get(channel.language).push(channel);
  
    return m;
  }, new Map()).values()];
  
  return channelGroups.map((channels) => ({
    ...rest,
    channels
  }));
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: With `channels.reduce((m, channel)` i get `Type 'IterableIterator<any>' is not an array type` which is weird because channel is definitely an array.

Comment: @MartijnvandenBergh - the reduce result is a Map, and not an array. And the `.values()` produces an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

way with lodash:

```
const res = _.chain(arr)
    .flatMap(item => _.map( // get array of channels with parent name
        item.channels,
        channel => _.assign({}, channel, { parentName: item.name })
    ))
    .groupBy('language') // group channels by language
    .values() // get channel arrays for each lang
    .map(langArrs => ({ // set finished structure
        name: _.first(langArrs).parentName, // get name for lang channels
        channels: _.omit(langArrs, ['parentName']) // set channels without parent name
    }))
    .value();
```